# Can you set cwd for abspath?

Tags: python, path, python-3.4

I am trying to expand out a relative path into an absolute path. The relative path will sometimes in include a `.` which will need to be expanded out from the current working directory. I was wondering if the any standard functions in Python accept a `cwd` kwarg, like `subprocess.popen` does.

**Optimal Solution**

```
abs_path = os.path.abspath(rel_path, cwd=special_cwd)
```

**Current Solution**

```
# Capture current working directory
previous_cwd = os.getcwd()

# Change to the new working directory
os.chdir(new_cwd)

# Convert relative path to absolute path
abs_path = os.path.abspath(rel_path)

# Change back to previous working directory
os.chdir(previous_cwd)
```

The current solution seems clunky, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.4

Comment: Based on the docs `abspath` is most often the same as `normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))`. So wouldn't it be `normpath(join(new_cwd, path))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The current solution seems clunky, is there a better way to accomplish this?

You can write your own code as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) which changes the directory and then changes back:

```
>>> from contextlib import contextmanager

>>> @contextmanager
... def cwd(path):
...     from os import getcwd, chdir
...     cwd = getcwd()
...     chdir(path)
...     yield
...     chdir(cwd)
```

then the actual code will look much cleaner:

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/user'

>>> with cwd('/usr/share'):
...     print(os.path.abspath('./test'))
... 
/usr/share/test

>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/user'
```